# Better way to convert angular animation callback into observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an angular animation, that has a callback when it completes:

```
<section [@routerTransition]="getAnimation()" (@routerTransition.done)="transitionEnd($event)">
</section>
```

I'm currently handling that event, and emitting from an EventEmitter:

```
private transitionCompleted$: EventEmitter<null> = new EventEmitter();

transitionEnd() {
    this.transitionCompleted$.emit();
}
```

`transitionCompleted$` is an observable (`EventEmitter` is a subclass of observable) that emits when the transition completes.

### Is there a better/more straightforward way to convert that callback into an observable?

What I don't like is having to handle that event, only to create a new event.

Something like `this.transitionCompleted$ = @ViewChild('@routerTransition').done` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no better way to do that at this point in time. They are currently working on a solution.

You can follow the [progress of this issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248).

Comment: Thank you, did not even know the terminology (cold event streams) 